# Why am I getting an unsupported operand error (PHP)?

Tags: php

I am testing a new feature and suddenly started getting an unsupported operand type error message. The code where the error is catching was not written by me, so I cannot change it. I have no idea why I'm getting an error at all.

The error says it's online line 76, which is

```
$transcripts[$inmateshort] = $job->getTranscript() + array(
    'inmatename' => $inmateshort,
    'inmatelong' => $inmatelong,
    'parentid' => $job->parentid
);
```

the else part of the if.

Here's more code:

I am calling the function here:

```
echo '<a href="' . site_url('invoice/copyTranscriptsToParent/' . $job['id']) . '" id="copyCreateInvoice">Copy transcripts to parent job</a>';
```

And this is the function:

```
function copyTranscriptsToParent($jobs) {
    $transcripts = array();
    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        $name = explode(' ', strtok($job->re, ';'), 2); 
        $nameshort = $name[1] . ', ' . substr($name[0], 0, 1); 
        $namelong = $name[1] . ', ' . $name[0]; 
        if (array_key_exists($nameshort, $transcripts)) {
            $transcripts[$nameshort]['personname'] = $transcripts[$nameshort]['namelong']; 
            $transcripts[$namelong] = $job->getTranscript() + array('personname' => $namelong, 'parentid' => $job->parentid);
        } else {
            $transcripts[$nameshort] = $job->getTranscript() + array('personname' => $nameshort, 'namelong' => $namelong, 'parentid' => $job->parentid);
        } 
    }
    $files = array();
    foreach ($transcripts as $transcript) {
        $origfilename = strtoupper($transcript['personname']);
        $filename = $origfilename;
        $i = 1;
        while (in_array($filename, $files)) {
            $i++;
            $filename = $origfilename . ' (' . $i . ')';
        }
        $files[] = $filename;
        $filename .= '.pdf';
        $attachmentid = $this->CI->MJob->getNewAttachmentId();
        $this->CI->S3->copyFile('uploads/' . $transcript['jobid'] . '/' . $transcript['origfilename'],
                            'uploads/' . $transcript['parentid'] . '/' . $filename,
                            $transcript['bucket']);
        $this->CI->MJob->updateAttachment($attachmentid, $transcript['parentid'], $filename, '', $transcript['personname'] . ' - transcript', 'application/pdf', 0, 'transcript', 0, $transcript['bucket']);
    }
    return count($transcripts);
}
```

As I said, I can't change this function, so why am I getting the error? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `var_dump($job->getTranscript());`?

Comment: It says it is null.

Comment: Well, there you go! You can't add an array to `null`.

Comment: You are right, of course. Thank you. I will have to look at this more.

Comment: I believe you have data stored in `$job->getTranscript()` as object or NULL, and then you are concatinating with array. Try using PHP function `array_merge()` for merge/concat two arrays.

Comment: @anujarora, I didn't write this function and cannot edit it, so I need to find a way around that. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you can alter `$job->getTranscript()`, then you can fix it. Return an empty array instead of null.

Comment: @Qirel, thank you for your help. Can you post something as an answer so that I can accept it for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, we discovered that `$job->getTranscript()` returns `NULL`. You cannot add an array to a `NULL` value, that will result in the following error.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Since you have stated that you cannot alter your `copyTranscriptsToParent()` function, you can edit your `getTranscript()` method to return an empty array on failure instead of null, so that you always add an array to an array.

Alternatively, you can make sure that whatever you pass into the `copyTranscriptsToParent()` function (the `$jobs`) have valid `getTranscript()` calls that does not return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it error free like below:-

```
if( !empty($job->getTranscript()) ) {

     if( gettype($job->getTranscript()) == "object") {
         //convert to array and store it to a variable
     }

     $getTranscript_data = $job->getTranscript();
} else {
     $getTranscript_data = array();
}


$transcripts[$inmateshort] = array_merge($getTranscript_data + array(
                                'inmatename' => $inmateshort,
                                'inmatelong' => $inmatelong,
                                'parentid' => $job->parentid
                             ));
```

[Details information for gettype function of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)